# PHP - Server side variables that will "live" for ever?

Tags: php, variables, server-side

I'm looking for a simple way to store a counter in the server memory to allow page load selection, kind of (pseudocode):

```
if counter is odd then load page-x 
else (even counter)  load page-y
increment counter by 1
store counter in server's memory
```

Session variables would not help, among multiple users.

I understand this could be achieved storing a field into the database, but this seems a cloggy approach. Was wondering for something faster.

That's why I thought about some server side variables that are kept in memory across sessions....

Comment: So this is a global counter? The same for every user?

Comment: Persistent data should be store in a database or files.

Comment: @Pekka, yes same for every user.

Comment: A 'cloggy' approach? I'm dutch, and I can appreciate clogginess, but don't you mean a 'kludgy' approach?

Comment: @Wrikken it's a word. It means [thick and sticky. Like in muddy](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0155780#m_en_gb0155780). But [kludgy](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0446540#m_en_gb0446540) is appropriate too (though it does not list an adjective there).

Comment: if you found what initialy you want, dont forget tell us, i will implement something like this in the near future, maybe "Semaphore, Shared Memory and IPC" is the solution??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a database connection already open, I would consider using that. I can't imagine that querying one row can give you performance problems under any kind of load.

If you don't want to do that, a simple and fast approach for your "odd/even" check could be using a temporary file.

- If the file exists, the condition is "odd"
- If it doesn't exist, the condition is "even"

make sure you build in a check against the [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) of two instances trying to create or remove the same file at the exact same time - you have to make sure the script doesn't crash in that case.

This solution, obviously, survives even a server restart.

Comment: And would assure a 50/50 solution (except in case of concurrent access, this would require a default page in case of failure).. What overhead, assuming the site has just 500 hundred page views per day?

Comment: @Riccardo overhead is totally negligeable, in the area of milliseconds. I think performance worries are unnecessary here. Use whichever method is most convenient, and easiest to implement and maintain for you. It's definitely not worth introducing a cache for.

Comment: I have sticked for your method basically because it offers a 50/50 solution, also in case of server restart and is very quick to be implemented. Memcache may be faster, however in my case iI need something just for testing purposes, once enough stats are collected, the code will be removed.

Answer (score 7):

Use APC, xCache, or memcache to save variables to cache instead of a database. Note however that a server reset will wipe out these values.

Comment: No problem, as it is just an odd/even "flag". Basically I want to alternate two pages, and see which one performs better! Any memcache primer?

Comment: the php docs are quite comprehensive enough. you need only a few functions to use it and they're pretty much self-explanatory: connect(), set(), get(), close().

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to is A/B testing. You would usually have a cookie that tracks an incoming visitor and then determines whether to serve version A or version B.

The reason you would use a cookie is because, if the user visits the same page and gets an alternative version, they're going to get confused. Using a cookie will put the visitor in either text group A or test group B, and serve the relevant page each time they visit (as long as the cookie lives).

Comment: WOW!! Very good point on this!! But you can fix this with a session variable. On session start, set "page version", then keep it handy for the whole session.... what do you think?

Comment: What if a user visits your site, gets page A, gets that set in the session, then closes the browser. Then, after lunch, they visit your site again, but gets page B instead?

Comment: Ok, no problem, just a few changes in the page layout (sidebar)

Comment: But like I and others have said, you would do this with a cookie and a random basis. Not a counter in a database or a server cache, both of which can be damaged.

Answer (score 3):

For true 50/50 easily, use a file:

```
$pageToShow = file_get_contents("whatever.dat");

if ($pageToShow == "A") {
    // show page a
    file_put_contents("whatever.dat", "B");
} else {
    // show page b
    file_put_contents("whatever.dat", "A");
}
```

Obviously create the file with just the letter "A" in it first.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [Shared Memory](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.shmop.php) extension if that's that simple?

[Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is generally used for data caching, optionallly distributed. You can start reading from [PHP memcache extension](http://www.php.net/memcache)'s pages.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was already mentioned, have a look at

- [PHP Dark Arts: Shared Memory Segments](http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-shared-memory-segments-ipc) and
- [PHP Dark Arts: Semaphores](http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-semaphores)

or in the PHP Manual:

- [Semaphore, Shared Memory and IPC](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.sem.php)

Comment: Unfortunately both test (running on Windows) environment, and the production server (apparently running on Linux) issue an error: Call to undefined function shm_attach. Maybe something disabled....

Comment: @Riccardo probably. See http://de.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php: *"Support for this functions are not enabled by default. To enable System V semaphore support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvsem. To enable the System V shared memory support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvshm. To enable the System V messages support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvmsg."*

Comment: @Riccardo you're welcome. On a sidenote, I really think you should use memcached or APC for this. The article series is titled Dark Arts for a reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a database, you could simple use a cache mecanism (as proposed in the other answer) or simply store your value in a text file. This will be slower than the cache, but has the advantage of persisting even after a server reset.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to do A/B testing, have you looked into [Google Website Optimizer](https://www.google.com/analytics/siteopt/splash?hl=en-GB&service=websiteoptimizer&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fsiteopt%2F%3Fet%3Dreset%26hl%3Den-GB&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-emea-uk-sk-gwo&medium=ha&term=a%2Fb%20testing), which allows you to do some quite detailed A / B analytics.

You can test out different pages, or page sections and figure out which one leads to more conversions.

I know this answer doesn't directly answer your technical question, but it may address the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just by chance, that you want to serve A or B, you could use a simple access time switch:

```
<?php
if (filemtime(".switch") % 2):
  require "A";
else:
  require "B";
endif;

touch(".switch");
```

This, obviously, doesn't serve as hard 50/50 solution.

Comment: I thought about this, however I need a 50/50 solution! Thanks!