# How can I store data in RAM memory using PHP?

Tags: php, memcached, shared-memory

Is there a way to store small data in RAM memory using PHP so that I can have access to the data between different session instead of regenerating it. Something similar to memcached (I don't have access to memcahced). My current solution is just to save the data in file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Server side variables that will "live" for ever?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086044/php-server-side-variables-that-will-live-for-ever) - there is a lot of answers in there that are applicable to your question.

Comment: Why? On any modern operating system (where storage is not on a shared filesystem) file data is cached in memory anyway.

Answer (score 14):

[APCu](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php)?

It works differents from memcached; in memcached you can access the data from various languages (c, python, etc..) while APCu works only for PHP.

Ensure that APC is installed correctly. Add `extension=apcu.so` in `php.ini`? Restart the server (apache, etc)

This is a simple test:

```
<?php
/*
 * page.php
 * Store the variable for 30 seconds,
 * see http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.apcu-add.php
 * */
if(apcu_add('foo', 'bar', 30)){
    header('Location: page2.php');
}else{
    die("Cant add foo to apcu!");
}

<?php
/*
 * page2.php
 * */
echo 'foo is been set as: ' . apcu_fetch('foo');
```

Consider using `apcu_add` over `apcu_store`; the only difference between them is that `apcu_add` doesn't overwrite the variable but will fail if called twice with the same key:

> Store the variable using this name. keys are cache-unique, so attempting to use apcu_add() to store data with a key that already exists will not overwrite the existing data, and will instead return FALSE. (This is the only difference between apcu_add() and apcu_store().)

It's a matter of taste/task of the script, but the example above works with `apcu_store` too.

Comment: He can't install memcached, so chances are he can't install APC either

Comment: True, but many hoster allow the use of APC (with some limitations) - we need to ask him.

Answer (score 8):

You could always use an in-memory DB to save the data.  Possibly overkill, though.

Comment: I'm surprised no one else upped your answer. I've had success using mysql memory tables and they're really fast. RDB might be overkill for sessions, but it's a great option when you don't have access to memcached or /dev/

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are on a shared server of some sort.

`memcached` or another caching solution is indeed the only way to do this.

Sessions, the most prominent method of persisting data across PHP pages, work based on files. You can change the session handler to be database based instead, but that's not RAM based, either.

As far as I can see, without changing your system on root level (e.g. to install memcached, or store session files on a RAM disk), this is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file in `/dev/shm` and it will be kept in memory until the machine is rebooted. This may or may not be faster than using any old file, depending on your usage pattern.

Comment: He seems to be on a shared server

Comment: @Pekka Well, then he's screwed... Let's just hope that his file gets cached by the OS.