# PHP: Hold in memory? or query DB?

Tags: php

Here's a design question. I have a certain lookup table that doesn't change. It will have about 1000 rows. It may change once every few months.

Should I be holding it in memory, having each PHP app instance 'load it up once' from the DB when it loads and serve it from memory? or should I just query the DB every time it's used?

If using this lookup was a "one million transactions per second" thing, it would have been a no brainer, in-memory. But it's not -- this may be called upon a few times a second only, maybe 5 or 6... but not anymore.

What would you do?

Comment: *'load it up once' from the DB when it loads and serve it from memory* That makes more sense for a  `lookup table that doesn't change`

Comment: Thinking about a multi web server instance + load balancer architecture  -- does it makes sense to load this info up in something like Redis or memcached and point all web server instances there?

Comment: I would still like to make occasional changes to this data this without changing PHP code.

Comment: sounds like a job for : http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Comment: You can try some caching mechanism like Redis or Memcached, which "load your data once and serve it from memory".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this link will be usefull for you
It works differents from memcached; in memcached you can access the data from various languages (c, python, etc..) while APC works only for PHP.

[How can I store data in RAM memory using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089361/how-can-i-store-data-in-ram-memory-using-php)